# How to deal with css and custom directive in angulajs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Consider a custom directive in angularjs:

```
.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: "..."
  }
})
```

As far as I see the tag `<my-dir></myDir>` has no default style associated (or, at least, it is not a block tag). Now I want to style it and place in the right point of my page. I have 2 alternatives:

1) Use this template:

```
.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: "<div class="layout">...</div>",
  }
})
```

And css:

```
.layout {
    /* bla bla bla */
}
```

But this introduce a new unnecessary level in the DOM three, since if I wrote something like `<my-dir class="layout"></my-dir>` with the proper css attached it would have worked anyway BUT I'll have to remember to add the same css class every time I use `<my-dir>` inside my code (and this is not `DRY`).

2) This led me to add style inside post-link function:

```
.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: "...",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.addClass('layout');
    }
  }
})
```

Which strategy is better? Are there pros or cons I can't see?

**UPDATE:**

Using `replace: true` in directive definition is not an option, since it has been deprecated and when using bootstrap things like `<my-dir class="visible-xs"></my-dir>` may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this problem by having `replace: true` option in your directive, which will basically replace your directive DOM with the template which you have given from your directive.

**Directive**

```
.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: "<div class="layout">...</div>",
    replace: true //added replace true property
  }
})
```

**Resultant HTML**

```
<div class="layout">..Content..</div>
```

Like above I shown, you could get rid off the unnecessary HTML tag by simply using `replace` option of directive.

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FF0GIz8xKPKYCZW7ONUa?p=preview)

> **Note**
>
> As per Angular Docs `replace` option has been deprecated in Angular2,
>   but in your case you can avoid that.

But if you really wanted to go avoid the use of `replace` option of directive then I'd suggest you to use your directive as an attribute instead of going for an `element` but then you need to take `<div class="layout">` outside and then your could put your directive over that like `<div class="layout" my-dir>`. But if you again think over it in Angular2 perspective, you are changing your component structure to old angular way using `attribute`/`class`

Comment: `replace` has been DEPRECATED! See https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/docs/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: @Sirion oh Thanks for sharing that..but still thinking about why it is working in angular `1.4.7` which my plunkr has..tried changing it to `replace: false` to `replace: true` its truely working. .did you noticed that? Event in `1.4.6` & `1.5.0-beta.1` version it seems working..

Comment: @Sirion have you read `replace ([DEPRECATED!], will be removed in next major release - i.e. v2.0)`?

Comment: Yes, but if they point it out it means we should not use it (imho).

Comment: @Sirion AFAIK you need to do complete rewrite when you migrate from Angular 1.X to Angular 2.. don't think that there would be an option like `replace` while declaring any component..I'd use that property until Angular suggest the alternative way of doing it..

Comment: You are probably right, but why did they labelled "only" this feature as deprecated? Looking through the docs I don't see many other deprecation alerts. Anyhow, I'll use this solution if nothing better comes up (really, no one has aver thought about this issue?)

Comment: I updated my question, please see above. I can't remove my downvote until you edit your answer.

Comment: @Sirion look at the updated answer..I don't think so there would be good way to do that..there might be a way which I missed..I'm really going to watch on this question for good answer